# How to format json from CSV that can be parsed by jQuery Datatables plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, csv, datatables

I am working with Rails and the jQuery Datatables plugin where I am trying to display data from a CSV in the view. The number of columns and rows varies from file to file, and relying on the view alone works perfectly for smaller files, but anything larger will obviously take a while for the page and subsequently the jQuery plugin to load (I require the pagination functionality). I have, therefore, changed to attempting to pass the td values to Datatables via its ajax/serverSide rendering features. The problem that I am currently dealing with is that I am continually getting the response that "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined".

I am currently using this code to parse out the CSV file and send from the controller:

```
json_hash =  CSV.parse(csv_file, headers: true)
json_hash = JSON.pretty_generate(json_hash.drop(1).map(&:to_h), {object_nl: '', indent: ' '})
respond_to do |format|
  format.csv {send_data csv_file, filename: scenario+".csv"}
  format.json { render json: json_hash  } 
end
```

Here is how I have DataTables set:

```
var scene = $("#data-table-id").val();
var table = $('#data-viz-table').DataTable({
  searching: false,
  bServerSide: true,
  deferRender: true,
  scrollCollapse: true,
  bProcessing: true,
  sAjaxSource: '/data_model/export_csv/' + scene,
  order: [],
 "columnDefs": [
      { "orderable": false, "targets": "_all" }
    ]
  });
```

I have checked in the network tab for the response, as well as console logging the data, and everything at least "looks ok" as far as formatting, but I am completely lost as to what I need to do to get the td items to display in within the tbody element.

Any Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked what value are you getting in `scene`. I think your DataTable is expecting an array but instead getting an object or nil. Try something like `dataSrc:''` option in the ajax definition so DataTable knows to expect an array instead of an object and make sure you ajax data source (`var scene = $("#data-table-id").val();` in this case I guess) is not nil.

Also, See [ajax options](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) for best practices and better options.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, I will look into your suggestions when I come back to this problem and let you know how it works out!